# Redefining operator precedence in a module for exported predicate

Tags: module, prolog, operators

I would like to write a module that exports a predicate where the user should be able to access a predicate `p/1` as a prefix operator. I have defined the following module:

```
:- module(lala, [p/1]).

:- op(500, fy, [p]).

p(comment).
p(ca).
p(va).
```

and load it now via:

```
?- use_module(lala).
true.
```

Unfortunately, a query fails:

```
?- p X.
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: p
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR:  X .
```

After setting the operator precedence properly, everything works:

```
?- op(500, fy, [p]).
true.
?- p X.
X = comment ;
X = ca ;
X = va.
```

I used SWI Prolog for my output but the same problem occurs in YAP as well (GNU Prolog does not support modules). Is there a way the user does not need to set the precedence themselves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can **export** the operator with the `module/2` directive.

For example:

```
:- module(lala, [p/1,
                 op(500, fy, p)]).
```

Since the operator is then also available in the module, you can write for example:

```
p comment.
p ça.
p va.
```

where `p` is used as a prefix operator.